# Spring Integration DSL Shutdown Strategy

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Currently I have this flow

```
package com.example.demo.flow;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.*;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.channel.MessageChannels;
import org.springframework.integration.file.dsl.Files;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * Created by on 03/01/2020.
 */
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TestFlow {

    @Bean
    public StandardIntegrationFlow errorChannelHandler() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from("testChannel")
                .handle(o -> {

                    log.info("Handling error....{}", o);
                }).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow testFile() {


        IntegrationFlowBuilder testChannel = IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("d:/input-files/")),
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000L).maxMessagesPerPoll(5)
                        .errorChannel("testChannel")))
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)))
                .transform(o -> {

                    throw new RuntimeException("Failing on purpose");

                }).handle(o -> {
                });

        return testChannel.get();


    }


}
```

I am planning to stop this flow due to shutdown but there could some files are part of the flow.
If I shut down the integration flow will the currently processing files still be done or they'll be stopped potentailly killing their threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If stop, but not destroy, everything in the process is going to be handled properly. Only new data is going to be emitted from the source or message channels. This is also natural graceful shutdown behavior of an `ApplicationContext` when you close it: it stops beans first letting them to finish whatever is in progress an only after that it destroys them.

Therefore so far you should be OK with your intentions. Share with us, please, your experience if it otherwise - and we will look into that ASAP with an appropriate fix if needed. The point is that it really was a goal during the stop phase to not emit new data, but let existing processed to finish gracefully. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#jmx-shutdown

Comment: Is there any example how to stop it ?

Comment: For that reason we need to understand what exactly you want to stop. See some docs on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#control-bus. So, if you really just want to stop polling files from that `d:/input-files/` dir, you just need to get that `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` bean from the `ApplicationContext` and call its `stop()`. Or use the mentioned Control Bus to send an appropriate `stop()` command. If it more broader, like the whole `IntegrationFlow` or even full `ApplicationContext`, we need to know those details.

Comment: OK so if I use ApplicationContext  stop it will destroy all the channels / flows right? But as long as it won't stop currently processing threads then I am good.
Can you confirm please?

Comment: Yes, that's what I saw from my experience. But that `stop()` does not destroy beans. It just move them to stopped state: they may not produce anything, but in most cases they finish processing what is in-flight.

Comment: So it's not guaranteed they will finish processing??

Comment: If it doesn't you come back to us. As long as you executions are non-interruptible, they are going to finish.

Comment: It does not work using stop for me usecae. can you please give me an example how can I stop SourcePollingChannelAdapter  only so it won't poller further

Comment: `e.poller(...).id("myPollingAdapter")`. Then you autowire it somewhere and call its `stop()`. Or just send a command message like `@myPollingAdapter.stop()` to the Control Bus endpoint!

Comment: When I autowire what is the class type to autowire ?

Comment: Huh? The `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`. You said it yourself. That the endpoint bean created from the `IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter())`

Comment: When I autowire and use the @Qualifer spring doesn't find it
please can you show me an example

Comment: I also tried to create global varian on standardintegrationflow and calling stop but it sstill going on

Comment: OK so if I autowire applicationContext and get a bean it works

Comment: You probably have a circular dependency on this `IntegrationFlow` from the place where you would like to autowire its part. You may consider to use a Control Bus for such a management `stop()` operation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#control-bus

Comment: Thans but I won't chagne to that as its already done but I am able to get hold of the bean using applicationContext , no issues